# Train a non Linear SVC model using Pyspark

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, bigdata, svm, apache-spark-mllib

Is there any way to train a non linear **SVC** model using **Pyspark**?
I've tried :

```
 from sklearn.svm import SVC
 svc = SVC(kernel="rbf", random_state=0, gamma=1, C=1)
 model = svc.fit(features, target)
```

(**features** and **target** are two dataframes converted into List). 
the problem is that I'de like to train with a component in **Pyspark** to speed up my training

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non linear SVC is not available (yet) in **Pyspark** on the date of today according to:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4638 if you check out the last comment of one member of Spark community:

> Non-linear kernels for SVMs in Spark would be great to have. The main barriers are:
>   Kernelized SVM training is hard to distribute. Naive methods require a lot of communication. To get this feature into Spark, we'd need to do proper background research and write up a good design.
>   Other ML algorithms are arguably more in demand and still need improvements (as of the date of this comment). Tree ensembles are first-and-foremost in my mind.